# How do I get started with angular-calendar from Matt Lewis

Tags: angular, calendar

Can anyone help me getting the calendar month view up on my angular page?

I followed the steps on this github page (https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-calendar) but nothing shown on my page. I'm very new to angular 2 and don't know much about it.

This is the code sniped from my application:

- app.module.ts code

> ```
> import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
> import { Component, NgModule} from '@angular/core';
> import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
> import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
> import { CalendarModule } from 'angular-calendar';
>
> import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
> import { FilterBarComponent } from './filter-bar/filter-bar.component';
> import { CalendarComp } from './calendar/calendar.component';
> import { InputFormComponent } from './input-form/input-form.component';
>
> @NgModule({
>   declarations: [
>     AppComponent,
>     FilterBarComponent,
>     CalendarComp,
>     InputFormComponent
>   ],
>   imports: [
>     BrowserModule,
>     FormsModule,
>     HttpModule,
>     CalendarModule.forRoot()
>   ],
>   providers: [],
>   bootstrap: [AppComponent]
> })
> export class AppModule {
>
> }
> ```

- This is the app.component.html code:

> This is header of calendar
>
> ```
>   <div>
>     <mwl-calendar-month-cell>
>       <h5>This is a calendar day</h5>
>     </mwl-calendar-month-cell>
>   </div>
> </div>
> ```

- I have not see anything change on the website and no calendar is shown. If anyone could write a simple code to show me how to get started I would be really appreciated.

Thanks!

- Update: These are the console errors that I got after running it.

> ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.ngfactory.js:23 ERROR CONTEXT
>   DebugContext_ View_AppComponent_0 @
>   ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.ngfactory.js:23 vendor.bundle.js:3256
>
> Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to
>   enable the production mode.
>   ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.ngfactory.js:23
>
> ERROR TypeError: Cannot
>   read property 'isPast' of undefined
>       at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.ngfactory.js:163)
>       at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (vendor.bundle.js:13054)
>       at checkAndUpdateView (vendor.bundle.js:12359)
>       at callViewAction (vendor.bundle.js:12717)
>       at execComponentViewsAction (vendor.bundle.js:12649)
>       at checkAndUpdateView (vendor.bundle.js:12360)
>       at callWithDebugContext (vendor.bundle.js:13416)
>       at Object.debugCheckAndUpdateView [as checkAndUpdateView] (vendor.bundle.js:12956)
>       at ViewRef_.detectChanges (vendor.bundle.js:10428)
>       at vendor.bundle.js:5285 View_AppComponent_0 @ ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.ngfactory.js:23
>   ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.ngfactory.js:23 ERROR CONTEXT
>   DebugContext_ View_AppComponent_0 @
>   ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.ngfactory.js:23

Comment: Did you check it? https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-calendar/tree/master/build-tool-examples

Comment: any errors in your browser console?

Comment: @yurzui I did check it but it doesn't help with my case.

Comment: I see. How do you build your app?

Comment: @Adyson Yes there is 4 console error I will update my post to include them.

Comment: Try this https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-calendar/blob/master/build-tool-examples/systemjs/app/app.component.ts#L6-L15

Comment: @yurzui These are the step that I have taken to build the project. First I install the package using npm. Then import 'angular-calendar' in the app.module.ts file, also add the module 'CalendarModule.forRoot()' in the import section of the app.module.ts. 

I don't have anything in the app.component.ts right now. And the code in the HTML tag as above. I have html tag like h1 tag saying "this is a test" below the calendar tag just to test if it show anything at all. It showed the h1 tag, but anything related to the calendar component doesn't show.

Comment: I've just realised this is nothing to do with fullCalendar. Please can you remove the tag. fullCalendar is a different product.

Comment: Are you using angular-cli? Did you include css?

Comment: @Adyson I did not have any tag said fullCalendar

Comment: @yurzui Yes I'm using angular cli, and I didn't include the css. I did tried yesterday but it keep saying path not found in chrome but in Webstorm the path is valid.

Comment: @DanielDang yes you did. Check the first revision: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44194545/revisions Yurzi removed it for you in revision 3, just after I mentioned it.

Comment: Check this repo https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-calendar/blob/master/build-tool-examples/angular-cli/angular-cli.json#L21 Here is full implementation for angular-cli

Comment: @yurzui Thank you so much! The css is what preventing my code from display. I managed to get something display on the page, but the content is just 1,2,3....31 I assume that is the current days in this month. No style is shown.